# After ajax call, date picker work but the formatting not

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

Below is the Ajax call in index.php

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(e) {
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
        var $txt = $(this).text();
        document.getElementById("pd").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("listpd").style.display = "none";
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "piutang.php",
            data: {"nama": $txt},
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#pd").html(msg)
                $("#formNama").val('');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The piutang.php (inside the Ajax call) has the text box for the date-picker and also the script for the date picker.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" name="tgl" style="width: 85px;" readonly />
<script>
        $(function() {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
        });

        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy"
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
</script>
```

After the call, inside the div with id:#pd,
I can see the text box of the date picker with the current date. 
But it show the default format `mm/dd/yyyy` not `dd M yy`.

What I've tried so far is cut the script code in piutang.php,
then paste/insert the code inside Ajax success, right after `$("#pd").html(msg)`,
but the result is the same thing, inside the div with id:#pd,
the text box show the current date with its default format `mm/dd/yyyy`.

How do I solve this ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you adding multiple input-boxes of date picker?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, there is another inputbox in piutang.pdhd, but it doesn't have an ID

Comment: Are you initializing the same datepicker 2 times? Why?

Comment: @Cr4id3r, no. The script at first I put in piutang.php, together with the textbox. I've tried delete all other thing in piutang.php, so it;s just left which exactly the same in my post for piutang.php. The same result, date format not working. Next, I remove all the code of the script in piutang.php (so, there is only the input box there in piutang.php), then I insert the code in index.php right after `$("#pd").html(msg)`. Still the same problem.

Comment: In the second snippet in your question, inside that script, you are initializing twice.

Comment: @El_Vanja, Oh... sorry I don't know that is initializing twice, because I just copy-paste the code from the internet. So, what should be the code please ?

Comment: Using just the second call to `.datepicker` (with the format setting and starting date) should be enough.

Comment: Just now I make the code like this : `$(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd M yy"
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());` , but then it doesn't work at all. No current date shown, also when I click the inputbox, no datepicker appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize date picker one time with all settings:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd M yy"
 }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

This one is enough. Remove other one.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alive to Die. It work as expected now.

Comment: @karma  glad to help you:)